# using rabbitMQ to transfer MySQL records

Tags: rabbitmq

I want to use rabbitMQ to store ***new*** transactions(records) that are happening in the local database into the remote similar database. 
Any suggestions, ideas on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you share the reason of wanting to use RabbitMQ as the store and forward mechanism to the remote database. I believe most databases already have mechanisms to replicate/backup to a remote database installation. These are tuned to the database and tend to work very reliably. RabbitMQ will not help you shard database operations across multiple remove database instances either.

Why RabbitMQ?

Comment: Well, I am not backuping the DB; like I said, what I want is to store new transactions that are happening in the local database into the remote db. The local DB PC is not permanently online(but the remote one is), but I do want to have the records be on the remote DB immediately when they become online hence why I want to queue the records using RabbitMQ.

Comment: Ok...then just have all incoming transactions go to the remote DB and sync your local DB to this remote DB. RabbitMQ cannot provide DB transaction guarantees. It can provide reliable message delivery, and the ability to keep messages in a queue until there is a consumer make use of them (subject to limitations on queue size).

Comment: What if I have multiple PCs of the same DB which have to sync to one remote DB. I thought MySQL does not support multiple masters=> 1 slave

Comment: Perhaps my understanding of your architecture is too limited, but perhaps you need to switch the master(s) and the slave.

Comment: I have many Point of sale systems with similar DBs which I want to store their records in one remote DB.

Comment: Ok..., I ve never built a POS system, but is it standard practice to have MySQL DBs on each POS? A centralized DB should be enough IMO. And offcourse that brings us back to RabbitMQ as the connection glue between the POS and the centralized DB.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sachin, I'l make up some diggings based on your suggestions.